# Android blank background asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm doing an Android project with Asynctask, and I can't set TextView text to be "Loading", it is just blank until the AsyncTask loads. How could I overcome this problem?

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("Loading today's fixtures & results");
    HTMLParser parser = null;
        try {
            parser = new HTMLoadTask().execute("http://www.skysports.com/football/fixtures-results").get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: did you try comment code after ``textView.setText();`` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the get() call in the end, as this waits for the task to finish and then it retrieves the result. This will lock-up the UI-thread.

> **get()**
>
> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

I don´t know what you are doing in the AsyncTask, but in onPostExecute() you should handle the result and set the text of the textview.